# Keep changes in a specific file when reverting to previous commit

Tags: git, reset

Lets say I have a file `keep_changes.rb`. I have been working on my branch for quite sometime and I found that I messed up big-time. So I want to restore the `HEAD` to a previous commit discarding all the changes except those I made in `keep_changes.rb`.
Is there a way so I can keep the changes in a specific file/files when I do

```
git reset --hard <sha>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "git stash" command to stash the keep_changes.rb file. Later on when you need that specific change just type in "git stash pop" to get back the changed file.

Thanks